# SplitView with TabBar with SwiftUI does not extend to the bottom of the view

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, tabbar, navigationview

So I am trying to display a splitView with a tabBar but the NavigationView does not stretch all the way to the bottom. Is there something I am missing?

here is the code I am using:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

protocol SettingsCoordinatorInput: ManagedCoordinator {
    
}

class SettingsCoordinator: ManagedCoordinator, SettingsCoordinatorInput {
    var navigationController = UINavigationController()
    weak var viewModel: SettingsViewModel?
    
    lazy var viewController: UIHostingController<SettingsSplitView> = {
        let viewModel = SettingsViewModel(coordinator: self)
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        return UIHostingController(rootView: SettingsSplitView())
    }()
    
    override func topController() -> UIViewController? {
        return viewController
    }
    
    convenience init(delegate: ManagedCoordinator) {
        self.init()
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
    
    override func start() {
        navigationController.viewControllers = [viewController]
    }
    
    @objc private func close() {
        finish()
    }
    
    override func finish() {
        super.finish()
        viewController.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

and the result is like this:
[image]

Comment: I observed such when someone included one NavigationView/Controller into another. Check your view hierarchy - there should be only one. Or provide minimal reproducible example to test.

Comment: I had a similar issue when i placed the tabbar wrong in the hierarchy.